Node Sync on GithUB too heavy to be deployed
![1](https://i.sstatic.net/gLRNo.png)
![2](https://i.sstatic.net/hQUlE.png)
![3](https://i.sstatic.net/5jyFo.png)

Thanks
Asked my teacher, he said my FTP host was too slow, but 431 Mb seem huge for me as well
Is it normal to have linux packages integrated ? Where is the issue ?
Takes 10 minutes (600 sec) and then it aborts everytime

Hey, do not add node_modules or external downloaded sources to the GitHub. Modules are the most of the MB in your project. Place node_modules or relevant modules to .gitignore and when you sync it from GitHub, use "npm install" after it and it will load everything from npm sources

I have answered it on the comments but here is the solution for the problem;
When you deploy a NodeJS application to the NodeJS, it pushes all the items and modules to the Github. The modules (dependencies or library) are added to the your project internally with saving them in node_modules directory.
These modules has their installed modules too and that modules have their installed modules too so in total that gets you to more than 200 MB for just a module in project.
Your installed and used modules are already noted and saved to you config files and they are used to re-install or setup program.
While pushing to the GitHub, do not push node_modules folder with it. To prevent this, you can add ./node_modules to .gitignore file. This will prevent it from uploading all the modules that is already in the internet.
If you download it from the GitHub or clone it and try to run it, it will not run without modules. To install them quickly or to sync all the modules into app you can use npm install command.
